# Background image only works when setting display property to list-item

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been trying to set a background image to a div in css i.e.

```
React.createElement("div", {className: "icon"})

.icon {
    background: url("../images/icons/icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Nothing seems to be displaying. I've also verified that the image is in the correct location.

However, when I set `.icon` to `display: list-item` i.e.

```
.icon {
    display: list-item;
    background: url("../images/icons/icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
 }
```

the image appears on the page. Is there any reason why display-list item works, but nothing else will? is there a way to get the background image working without having to use `display: list-item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends: Does your `.icon` DIV have any content?

Because, if a DIV doesn't contain anything, it has no size (i.e. height zero), so you wouldn't see a background-image.

However, a `li` by default is always at least one line high (i.e. the line-height that's defined for it) and 100% wide, even if there is no content, so you'll see a background-image...

Comment: No, the icon div has no content. It's like it is in the code snippet.

What you said about the list item makes a lot of sense. I tried setting min-width and min-height on my empty div, but it doesn't fix the issue like `display: list-item` does

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following;

Create a div with the following css code:

```
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url("INSERT URL HERE");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

That should create a perfect square on the page with the image you post between the quotations as its background.